# Apple MacBook Pro M1 chip + Postgres + Connection refused error

Tags: postgresql, apple-m1

I am getting the below error in my MacBook Pro M1 chip

```
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In the MacBook Air I used to resolve this error by removing postmater.pid from /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid directory.

But not able to find this pid in MacBook Pro M1 BigSur OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MacBook Pro M1 chip you can find postmater.pid in the below directory.

```
/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1/opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

I have removed that and restarted Postgres. Now everything is running perfectly.

Comment: removing postmaster.pid file worked for me. I have removed postmaster.pid this file and restarted postgres using brew

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac Mini with M1, postmaster.pid was here:
`/System/Volumes/data/opt/homebrew/var/postgres`

Answer (score 0):

the `/System/Volumes/data/opt/homebrew/var/` works
just remember if you installed a different version that it might be tagged differently eg: `/System/Volumes/data/opt/homebrew/var/postgres@12`

i have personally encountered this many times. So it might be a good idea to make an alias in your shell to easily remove that again
using zshrc:

`alias psk='rm /System/Volumes/data/opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid'`